# how to show datepicker calendar on datefield

Tags: django, django-models

This is regarding how to use a jQuery `date picker` in a django powered site.

`models.py` is

```
from django.db import models
class holidaytime(models.Model):
    holiday_date = models.DateField()
```

I am using `jquery datepicker`.

I am using a `model form` and created `text field` for displaying date sucessfully.

But failed to show a datepicker icon.  I am using Django model forms.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use `widget` to pass a `class` to the form when it will be rendered in the html. Then that `class` will be read by `javascript` to render the `datepicker` function.

Here is an example:

```
from django import forms
class HolidayTimeForm(forms.Form):
    holiday_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=
                                {
                                    'class':'datepicker'
                                }))
```

... or through the `widgets` attribute in the Meta class when using ModelForm:

```
class HolidayTimeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Holiday
        widgets = {
            'holiday_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}),
        }
```

Now in template:

```
 /* Include the jquery Ui here */
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      yearRange: "1900:2012",
      // You can put more options here.

    });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: You probably should use a class, not an id.  What if you have more than one copy of this form on the page, or two dates in the same form?

Comment: Couldn't get this to work. The answer below worked, and provided me with more flexibility.

Answer (score 15):

You can use [Bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) (not datepicker), here is an example:

1. Add necessary script & file into your template:

```html
<link href="//cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.44/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.44/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

2. add class/id to your datetime fields by using widget:

   ```
   class MyTaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = MyTask
   fields = ['completeDateTime']
   widgets = {
       'completeDateTime': forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'datetime-input'})
   }
   ```
3. Add the script to your template/html file: (NOTICE the format, it's import to use the same format of the Django)

```js
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.datetime-input').datetimepicker({
            format:'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: get time/date picker only by changing format. e.g.  format:'HH:mm'