# Jquery datepicker django

Tags: jquery, python, django

I've been trying to get the jquery datepicker to work on django, I've looked at
[Show datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356289/how-to-show-datepicker-calender-on-datefield) but I've had no luck.

My Date is defined as

```
    date = models.DateTimeField('Published Date')
```

My date in the form is setup as:

```
class UploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Archive
        widgets = {
            'date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'}),
               }
```

In My upload.html

```
{% extends 'budget/base_form_views.html' %}
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    changeMonth:true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: 1900:2100,})
  });
</script>
//generated form//
```

The upload.html extends base_form.html and all the scripts are loaded there

```
<head>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'budget/js/jquery-1.10.2.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'budget/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'budget/js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'budget/css/jquery-ui.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'budget/css/bootstrap.css' %}" />

</head>
```

Nothing happends when I click on the date text field, In the firefox console, all scripts and css's get load with no errors.

I'm using Django 1.6.5.

Is there something that I'm missing?

edit: forgot to add Upload View to post.

```
class UploadView(FormView):
    template_name = "budget/upload.html"
    form_class = UploadForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('view')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally managed to get it to work.

The UploadForm

```
class UploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'}))
    ....
```

The upload.html file contains

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Just a reminder that upload.html extends my base.html which houses all the jquery scripts

Answer (score 0):

In your view, did you specify a form to be used? This can be done as shown below.

## Views.py

```
class YourView():
    model = Archive
    # (Note that UploadForm must be imported to be used here) 
    form_class = UploadForm
```

Comment: I forgot to add my view to the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by giving an 'id' to the form and calling the JQuery code on the id instead of the class:

**forms.py**

```
  'date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker', 'id': 'my_date'})
```

**upload.html**

```
 $('#my_date').datepicker({...
```

Comment: try these for jquery:
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: still no luck with those links.