# DateTimeField has no datepicker in Django admin

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin

I use Django 1.7.11. There is a model with DateTimeField and it's missing datepicker in Django admin, it has only a text field. What can I do to use datepicker in admin?

models.py:

```
class Phase(models.Model):    
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

admin.py:

```
class PhaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
admin.site.register(Phase, PhaseAdmin)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to show datepicker calender on datefield](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356289/how-to-show-datepicker-calender-on-datefield)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. Need to run the command:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```