# DateField doesn't work in forms.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to create a date input field, but it shows as a simple input text, i'm using django 1.10, thanks in advance.

```
from django import forms
import datetime
from .models import Student

class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ["name","date"]
        widgets = {
            'date': forms.DateInput(format="%d/%m/%Y")}
```

Comment: And what are you expecting instead?

Comment: I'm expecting a date input, as in <input type="date"/>

Comment: This one should help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356289/how-to-show-datepicker-calender-on-datefield

Comment: Still didn't work, by creating the form from the Model Form class, it doesn't create the forms according to the types of the models, all inputs created are type text