# django date picker input in template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

I´m trying to use a date picker widget from a model form in the template. I´ve seen several posts but couldn´t get it working correctly.

The one I´m trying now is: [Answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356289/how-to-show-datepicker-calendar-on-datefield)

**Form.py**

My form code looks like

```
class FormularioTareas(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Tareas
    widgets = {'fecha_limite': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'})}
    fields = ["destinatario", "titulo", "tarea", "resuelto", "fecha_limite"]
```

**Template**

In the template I add this script:

```
 /* Include the jquery Ui here */
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      yearRange: "1900:2012",
    });
  });
 </script>
```

And have this form call in the html

```
<div style="background: white;">{{ tareas_form.fecha_limite }}</div>
```

**Jquery**

I load Jquery as follows and have no problems detected in the browsers console.

```
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

**What I get**

I found out that the picker is working, but the main text box diplays options down when focused so I didn´t see it. The text box is still behaving as a date picker and as a text box. How can I prevent this?

Any clues welcome. Thanks!

Comment: by any chance when you open the  developer console in chrome can you see ..datepicker isn't defined anywhere !!?or any other error ?

Comment: Hi @LeLouch I just updated the question with the info about browser console errors

Comment: that's not a django problem that's Jquery Problem and most likely the fix is [link ] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212696/jquery-ui-datepicker-datepicker-is-not-a-function)

Comment: @LeLouch I´ve checked that Jquery is only loaded once in my HTML. Like this: <script src="/static/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: @LeLouch I noticed I was missing the Jquery UI call. I updated the question. I have no problem with the console now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used  autocomplete="off" on the form so the usual text input dropdown options don´t show.